# How to solve: $z''=-c/z^4$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like tho solve the following nonlinear second order differential equation

$\frac{d^2{z}}{d{t^{2}}}=-\frac{c}{z^4}$

Where $C$ is a constant.

I have try to use this steps http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/second/nonlineareq/nonlineareq.html with no success.

Also, I've tryed to use the solver in Matlab, and they give me an error.

I don't think that this ODE is impossible to solve analytically.

Thank you in advance

Comment: have you tried WolframAlpha? the solution of your equation can not expressed by the known elementary functions

Comment: $\frac{\partial^2{z}}{\partial{t}^{\color{red}{2}}}=-\frac{c}{z^4}$ ... You don't need partial differentiation ? ... please clarify that you mean the second derivative.

Comment: What error did you get? Also you will need to specify two IC's

Comment: I can get as far as 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{dz}{dt}= \sqrt{2Cz^3+A}
\end{eqnarray*}
& I really don't fancy solving this (especially in light of Dr SB's remark ... By the way is there a Rainbow there today ?) ... $\ddot \smile$ 
@Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: I get $\frac{dz}{dt}=\sqrt{2Cz^{-3}+A}$, and solving this 1º order ODE, finally i have: $z(t)=\left( \frac{5}{2}\right)^{2/5}\cdot{\left(\frac{2\cdot{C}}{3}\right)^{1/5}}\cdot{t^{2/5}}+cnt$, but this is not true, because the equation descrive an atractive force, and the equation shows that for $t>0$ $z(t)>z_{0}$, maybe I'm missing something

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit If I only have one variable $\frac{\partial^2{z}}{\partial{t}^2}=\frac{d^2{z}}{d{t}^2}$? I'm a bit comfused about this.

Comment: $z$ is only a function of $t$ so we would write the derivative as $\frac{dz}{dt}$ ... as opposed to if $z$ was a function of two variables $z(x,t)$ then if we want to consider $x$ as constant & differentiate with respect to $t$ (only) then we would write $ \frac{ \partial z} {\partial t}$.

Answer (score 2):

As rightly said by Claude Leibovici whom I salute, the solution would be "a true monster" if we want to express it on a closed form with elementary functions. To make it simpler, we need an inverse special function as shown below.

NOTE: The initial conditions are not specified in the wording of the question. Don't forget that with some initial conditions the arbitrary constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ might have particular values which make the result much simpler involving functions of lover level than the Beta and Inverse Beta functions.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*This is more a comment than an answer.*

Using the classical $$\dfrac{d^2x}{dy^2}=-\frac{\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}}{\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^3}\implies\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-\frac{\dfrac{d^2x}{dy^2}}{\left(\dfrac{dx}{dy}\right)^3 }$$ So, for the differential equation you posted $$\frac{d^2{z}}{d{t^{2}}}=-\frac{c}{z^4}\implies \frac{d^2{t}}{d{z^{2}}}=\frac{c}{z^4}\left(\frac{d{t}}{d{z}}\right)^3$$ Cheating (which means using a CAS), there is an explicit solution for $t$ as a function of $z$ but the result is $\color{red} {\text{a true monster}}$ which involves a bunch of elliptic integrals with very nasty arguments. I shall not try to type the solution here. May be, if you really want fun, try using Wolfran Alpha or Matlab.